# Question answered partially by several users

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

I have asked a question where two users commentated. After a while, I found the "answer" to my question, the problem is that one wrote a comment and the other one an answer. Separate, the answer and the comment isn't enough to answer my question, but if both were written as one answer, I would make it the accepted answer. If it was just one user, it would not be a problem, but with two, I don't know what to do.

**How do I deal with this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several possibilities and what you do is entirely up to you

1. Don't accept anything (this doesn't help much, IMHO, or make sense but it's an option)
2. Accept the only "answer" (if doing this you may suggest that the author edit with the commented information
3. Write your own answer using all of the information from both the comment and the answer (if doing this I would upvote the answer that helped)

Option 3 is definitely the best way to go in this situation, IMO. If going with this, as Robert Harvey said, you could also make this a community wiki. This would make it easier for the other two (and others) to edit in if they could explain the solution further.

These are some of your options but, again, what you do is up to you. Whichever you choose, I would suggest thanking both people for their efforts and help...it's the polite and respectful thing to do.

Comment: Option 3 is one of the few legitimate remaining uses for Community Wiki.

Comment: @codeMagic I think I go whith option 3, but what is a community wiki and how do I create it?

Comment: [Community Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)